# Path clustering or segmentation

Tags: path, cluster-computing

I want to show categories customer path in percentage:
data (x,y) came from camera with costumer id
for example:
(x,y,customerid)
(10,10,1)
(10,12,1)
(11,13,1)
...
[image]

In first step thought,best way is using a clustering methos such as kmeans.
but there is some problem
the proper number of clustered group is ambigius.
clustering must be base on start point and related path(not base on points).
regression (or any related method) line must cross the nth clustered point from start point to end point.